# PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:withParameter:block: return value

Tags: ios, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

**In have a problem to Change CalUsed value I want to put Data in NSNumber *CalUsed1 to CalUsed for use in other function**

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSNumber *CalUsed;



- (void) GetCalUsed{
PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
[PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"CalUsed"
                   withParameters:@{@"user": user.objectId}
                            block:^(NSNumber *CalUsed1, NSError *error) {
                                if (!error) {
                                    NSLog(@"Calories : %@",CalUsed1);
                                    CalUsed = CalUsed1;
                                }
                                CalUsed = CalUsed1;
                                NSLog(@"TDEE IN FN is : %@",CalUsed);
                            }];
}


- (void) TestPrint{
NSLog(@"TDEE OUT FN : %@",CalUsed);
}
```

RESULT

TDEE OUT FN : (null)

Calories : 700

TDEE IN FN : 700

but I need global variable "CalUsed" change value to 700

Comment: As far as I can see, you're calling `TestPrint` before the block gets executed.

Comment: I do not understand block condition

Comment: Then go find a tutorial on blocks / asynchronous operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some Parse methods have a `block` in them. Because there will always be a delay in retrieving the data, there needs to be someone that the app "waits" until the data is retrieved. Unfortunately there is no easy way to do this so the `block` is there so anything that is within it will run AFTER the data is retrieved. If you put your `NSLog` in the block, it should work.

You have to remember that goal of any program is to execute the code as fast as possible. So when you call the Parse method, anything below it, NOT in the `block` will continue to run.

---

**Update**

If your going to use Parse you must understand the following (if you don't, there's no use in using Parse). Any parse functions that have a `block` will act differently than you would expect.

```
- (void) GetCalUsed{
PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
[PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"CalUsed" //This is the Parse function
               withParameters:@{@"user": user.objectId}
                        block:^(NSNumber *CalUsed1, NSError *error) { // This is where the block starts
                            if (!error) { //if the block retrieves the data with no problem, this will run
                                NSLog(@"Calories : %@",CalUsed1);
                                CalUsed = CalUsed1;
                            }
                            CalUsed = CalUsed1;
                            NSLog(@"TDEE IN FN is : %@",CalUsed);
                        }];
```

}

The thing about `callFunctionInBackground` is that there isn't really a way to return a value. So try to follow me: When the function is called, it will create a request to the Parse database to retrieve the data. But no matter how strong your connection, there will always be a delay (even if it is by milliseconds it still counts as a delay). Like I said before, the compiler wants to execute the code as fast as possible so this delay is going to cause problems. Using the above code, the Parse function will be called, however, as the app waits to retrieve the data, it's going to continue executing everything OUTSIDE of the Parse method. This is why your getting the `null` value (the `NSLog` outside of `callFunctionInBackground` is executed before the data is returned from Parse). To prevent this from happening, anything that involves `calUsed1` or `calUsed` **must** go inside the `block`. Just like this:

```
- (void) GetCalUsed{
PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
[PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"CalUsed"
                   withParameters:@{@"user": user.objectId}
                            block:^(NSNumber *CalUsed1, NSError *error) {
                                if (!error) {
                                    NSLog(@"Calories : %@",CalUsed1);
                                    CalUsed = CalUsed1;

                                   //HERE YOU CAN MANIPULATE THE DATA HOWEVER YOU WISH. YOU CAN CALL A METHOD OR DO SOMETHING ELSE (aka, you can do whatever you want here)
                                }

        }];
}
```

All in all, everything inside the `block` will be run only after the data from Parse has been retrieved...no matter how long it takes. If you still have questions feel free to ask.

Comment: How can i return CalUsed1 value to put in CalUsed ?

Comment: @bosz.KCH I have updated my answer. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am beginner I will ask you soon.

Comment: @nick9999 what if the block running in background failed? Like it timed out or so, how could the caller be notified?